# DB Design - Linking to a parent without circular reference issues

Tags: database-design, circular-reference

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for the following issue.

Lets say i have a db that looks something like the following:

**Issue Table**

```
Id | Details | CreateDate | ClosedDate
```

**Issue Notes Table**

```
Id | ObjectId | Notes | NoteDate
```

**Issue Assignment Table**

```
Id | ObjectId | AssignedToId| AssignedDate
```

I'd like allow the linking of an issue to another issue.
I thought about adding a column to the Issue table called ParentIssueId and that would allow me the ability to link issues, but i foresee circular references occurring  within the issue table if i go through with this implementation.
Is there a better way to go about doing this, and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table:

```
LinkedIssues
IssueIDa    pk composite primary key, fk to Issue table
IssueIDb    pk composite primary key, fk to Issue table
```

the PK will keep some duplicates away, but create a check constraint: `IssueIDa<IssueIDb` so you don't end up with a duplicate like:

```
row 1 IssueIDa=123
      IssueIDb=987

row 2 IssueIDa=987
      IssueIDb=123
```

however to prevent a circle like:

```
row 1 IssueIDa=123
      IssueIDb=987

row 2 IssueIDa=987
      IssueIDb=456

row 3 IssueIDa=456
      IssueIDb=123
```

you'll need a trigger that resolves the chain, and fails on a circle.  Using a recursive CTE would be your best bet to detect this circle.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not really familiar on how to create the trigger  using recursive cte to detect a circle like that. Do you have any examples or links that might help me get off on the right foot?

Comment: try this: [Microsoft SQL Server: Detecting Circular References.](http://database.itags.org/sql-server/80686/) or this: [Find circular references in single table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30491/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a join/link-table that would look something like this:

**IssueLink**

```
IssueId | LinkedIssueId
```

Where both columns are foreign keys to the Issue table.

This will allow you to link issues arbitrarily as well as allow a single issue to be linked to several others with the Parent-style relationship.

You'll want to put a unique index on the two columns so you don't end up with repeated data and also test to make sure that there is no condition such as this:

```
IssueId & LinkedIssueId = LinkedIssueId & IssueId
```

(which would result in a logical duplicate)

Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table
The only difference is that the Junction table points to the same table to create the one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If an issue may be related to one other "parent" issue, then haveing a "ParentId" column in the table is fine (with NULL meaning no parent). If an issue may be related to more than one other issue, then a new "many-to-many" (or "link") table will be required.

In **either** case, checking for and preventing circular references (particularly when the "circle" encompasses three or more issues) will be tricky. Either you check for the circle during the UPDATE by basing the update on a CTE that checks for circular references and fails the update if any are found, or you could update in a stored procedure that first checks for circles, and only issues the update if the check passes. (Of course, you have to worry about concurrency issues--what if the data gets changed between your check and your update--which makes the CTE-based update preferrable, if more complex.)